# React Convert class component to Functional component not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to convert my class Component to functional component but it doesn't work.

the problem comes from this line `previousLocation = this.props.location;`
how can i replace that in functional component

```
class App extends Component {
    previousLocation = this.props.location; //the problem comes from here
    render() {
        const { location } = this.props;
        const isModal = !!(
            location.state &&
            location.state.modal &&
            this.previousLocation !== location
        );
        return (
            <div>
                <Switch location={isModal ? this.previousLocation : location}>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Gallery} />
                    <Route exact path="/img/:id" component={Gallery} />
                    <Route exact path="/img" component={ModalPage} />
                </Switch>
                {isModal ? <Route path="/img/:id" component={ModalPage} /> : null}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

what I'm trying to do

```
const App = (props) => {
    const {previousLocation} = props.location;
    const {location} = props;
    const isModal = !!(
        location.state &&
        location.state.modal &&
        previousLocation !== location
    );
    return (
        <div>
            <Switch location={isModal ? previousLocation : location}>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Gallery}/>
                <Route exact path="/img/:id" component={Gallery}/>
                <Route exact path="/img" component={ModalPage}/>
            </Switch>
            {isModal ? <Route path="/img/:id" component={ModalPage}/> : null}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: can you provide more detail on what exactly isn't working?

Comment: Could you be more specific on what error it been given? Or any code above the App component?

Comment: i am rendering a modal in the same screen changing only the url, when i convert the class to functional, the modal doesn't appear anymore and it push to the route who might appear in modal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to get the previous props or state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state)

```
const usePrevious = value => {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });
  return ref.current;
}
```

Usage:

```
const App = ({ location }) => {
  // get previous location and cache current location
  const previousLocation = usePrevious(location);

  const isModal = !!(
    location.state &&
    location.state.modal &&
    previousLocation !== location
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <Switch location={isModal ? previousLocation : location}>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Gallery}/>
        <Route exact path="/img/:id" component={Gallery}/>
        <Route exact path="/img" component={ModalPage}/>
      </Switch>
      {isModal ? <Route path="/img/:id" component={ModalPage}/> : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Oh, I did help you earlier! I was like, "Man, what are the chances two questions in one day about react hooks and trying to access a previous value." Anytime.